# What part of the Android life cycle is involved (if any) when going back through backStack returns to main activity from a sequence of fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm trying to learn the `Fragment` class. Here's `MainActivity`:

```
    package com.dslomer64.hour8appflip;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        Button btnStartGarcon, btnStartWaiter;

        @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btnStartGarcon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartGarcon);
            btnStartWaiter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartWaiter);
            ableButtons(true);
        }
        @Override protected void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            ableButtons(true);
        }
        @Override protected void onRestart(){
            super.onRestart();
            ableButtons(true);
        }
        @Override protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            ableButtons(true);
        }
        public void showFragmentGarcon(){
            FragmentGarcon fragmentGarcon = new FragmentGarcon();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragmentGarcon);
            ft.addToBackStack("Garcon");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
        public void showFragmentWaiter(){
            FragmentWaiter fragmentWaiter = new FragmentWaiter();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragmentWaiter);
            ft.addToBackStack("Waiter");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
        public void onStartGarcon(View view) {
            showFragmentGarcon();
            ableButtons(false);
        }
        public void onStartWaiter(View view) {
            showFragmentWaiter();
            ableButtons(false);
        }
        private void ableButtons(boolean b){
            btnStartWaiter.setEnabled(b);
            btnStartGarcon.setEnabled(b);
        }
    }
```

Upon launch, the screen is at left. After first button tap, it's at right, because I decided it would be best to disable the MainActivity buttons then.

[image][image]

But when I tap the `back` icon enough times to exhause the `backStack`, no matter what I do (see the very redundant `ableButtons(true)` in `onStart`, `onRestart` `onResume`), the buttons are still disabled.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out (it has nothing to do with the Android life cycle):

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

...

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if( fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
        ableButtons(true);
    }
}
```

And use `fm` in `showFragmentGarcon` and the other `showFrag...`:

```
  public void showFragmentGarcon(){
        FragmentGarcon fragmentGarcon = new FragmentGarcon();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  //                             ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

> What part of the Android life cycle is involved (if any) when going
>   back through backStack returns to main activity from a sequence of
>   fragments?

The Activity life cycle is not involved. When you replace a Fragment you don't leave the activity, so you don't return to it.

> But when I tap the back icon enough times to exhause the backStack, no
>   matter what I do (see the very redundant ableButtons(true) in onStart,
>   onRestart onResume), the buttons are still disabled.

This is the expected behavior. You disabled the buttons and it is up to you enable them again when the `backStack` is empty. For instance you could override onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); 

  if (count == 0){
      ableButtons(true);
  } 
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: @Blackbelt--You beat me by 3 minutes! While I was editing, you posted. Glad I figured out a similar solution first. It seems to work, but you conditinally call `super.onBackPressed`. Do you think mine is OK? Maybe I miscounted...

Comment: @Blackbelt--Actually, yours doesn't compile. Where does `getSupportFragmentManager()` come from? I.e., what should I import?

Comment: it is part of the support library. I strongly suggest you to use this one. It's part of support library, and with each revision you will get the latest bugfixes. If you don't call `super.onBackPressed()`, you lock your users indefinitely in your app, which is probably something you want to avoid

Comment: I call `super.onBackPressed` at line 1 of my `onBackPressed`. And when I use my `onBackPressed` with your logic (i.e., `if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1){ableButtons(true);}else if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) super.onBackPressed();` things don't go right at all. Last fragment remains on screen.

Comment: I just edited mine, too, to include my equivalent of your new `if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0)`. Same problem. Last fragment remains on screen.

Comment: I'm not sure why to not call `super....` at line 1 and why the count = 1 signals enable buttons--why not count = 0?

Comment: (Deleted previous comment) Only way I can get MainActivity to remain active after pressing `back` enough times is the way I've coded it.